# log every laravel action that happen?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

where is the appropriate place to catch every time laravel is used even non http based action?

I want to catch everything even artisan commands, Queues or Task that running.

the only place I can think of is `bootstrap\app.php`
but its too hacky and with my experience with laravel I am sure there is some built in way of doing it

is there some one place to catch them all?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers may be your best bet.

Comment: hmm does they loaded even with queues and tasks? thanks :)

Comment: Yes, Laravel's service providers are loaded in queue workers and tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your logger to your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`'s `boot()` function.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Your logger goes here
        error_log('log...');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```